# Heroku Django App with local Database

Tags: django, heroku

Good morning, I was wondering, if its possible to deploy a django application on Heroku with a pg database (or any other database engine) on a local server, not within Heroku. If its so, how do you connect the app to the local server?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Heroku-Django Skel

https://github.com/michaelmior/heroku-django-skeleton

Comment: I think he was asking about specifically how to have the database be your own, while the app is running on Heroku.   I believe he will have discovered the answer is "only with great difficulty, why would you want to do that?"